# How to send Twilio SMS via Web Service in Salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce, twilio, apex

I want to send SMS from Twilio noticed they have libraries built for Java, .Net, Node, etc. so that we can use them if we are upto those technologies.

But I want to do the same from Salesforce Apex and trying to figure out how to build the Http parameters to make the authorization.

I tried to map with cURL example given in Twilio documentation and can't find header keys for Auth token.

Below is my current code and looking for how to set the authentication params.

```
req.setEndpoint(baseURL + '/2010-04-01/Accounts/account_sid/Messages.json');
req.setMethod('POST');                
req.setHeader('to', EncodingUtil.urlEncode('+to_number', 'UTF-8'));
req.setHeader('from', EncodingUtil.urlEncode('+from_number', 'UTF-8'));

Http ht = new Http();
HttpResponse res = ht.send(req);
```

---

Updated request :

```
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf('my-twilio-account-sid:my-twilio-auth-token');
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
String body = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('From=+from_number&To=+to_number&Body=Sample text from twilio', 'UTF-8');
req.setBody(body);
Http ht = new Http();
HttpResponse res = ht.send(req);
```

Response saying

> Bad Request : A 'From' phone number is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone numbers don't go in the headers.

For the headers you will need

`Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

then you will need another header for authorization

`Authorization: auth-string`

where `auth-string` is a combination of the string `Basic` followed by a space followed by a base64 encoding of `twilio-account-sid:twilio-auth-token` (replace with your Twilio credentials joined by the colon) so the header will look something like

`Authorization: "Basic ABCiDEdmFGHmIJKjLMN2OPQwR2S3TUVzABliCDE3FGc1HIo2JKL2MjNwOPcxQRSwTUc1Vzc0XmYhZAB3CDElFGH1Jw=="`

The `body` of the POST request should contain key, value pairs of `To`, `From` and `Body`, something like

`"From=" + twilio-phone-number + "&To=" + to-number + "&Body=" + message-body` (replace with string values for phone numbers and message).

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I think I proceeded to the next level with your answer by applying these changes. However I'm getting 400 Bad request as the response. I've updated the OP with my updated Http request. Can you please have a look on what is wrong there?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Actually I'm setting the numbers in the body string itself. just replaced them with `from_number` and 'to_number' in order to post here(without actual numbers) It's something like `EncodingUtil.urlEncode('From=+18888888888&To=+15555555555&Body=Sample text from twilio', 'UTF-8');` in real code

Comment: Yeah it's the twilio number in my code which I got from the success call from API explorer. not the numbers in comment or in post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178090/discussion-between-highfive-and-alex-baban).

Comment: issue was when the '&' is getting encoded it seems. When using below string as the body(encode only the '+') request was success.
`'From=%2B18888888888&To=%2B15555555555&Body=Sample text from twilio'`